# Add trusted file excel via reg file

Tags: excel, vba, registry

I am deploying a macro entry file to various people. I would like the computer to trust this file ask quickly as possible. Some system can trust as easily as one click `Enable macro`. Other have to trust the location. Trusting the file is more secure than trusting the location. How can I make a reg file to trust the file in various office versions (only 2010-2016 and window only).
I have gone to more than 10 page of Google search but found nothing I can do.
I found only this [guide](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/registry/tree/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Office/application_version/application_name/Security/Trusted-Documents/TrustRecords/index) but I am not familiar with PowerShell.

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA solution to merge a .reg file, into the registry?

Comment: I am looking for reg file content itself.